# How can settings from existing Redmine installation be imported into new installation?

Tags: import, settings, redmine

I have created some Redmine installations and would love to import the settings from a pre-existing installation. Things like Issues, News, Documents, Wiki Pages, Messages, Projects should be left behind and stuff like Groups, Issue Status, Custom fields ,Settings,Enumerations be imported.

Is there a tool or script which can do that?

I also suppose that the database can be copied, but stuff like issues, documents etc left behind. Is there some script or SQL that can do just that, delete the issues, wiki pages etc, or some subset of them?

Another thing I would like to be able to import are the custom queries?

If there is an administrative page or plugin where I can delete Issues, Projects etc that would also be great.

/vfclistsGUY

Answer (score 0):

You would need to migrate the DB and copy the files in [redmine]/files. It's pretty easy to backup a DB a file.

Follow through the steps of
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade

---

It boils down to:

1. create a copy of the DB and files -the "mind" of a Redmine install
2. Install a new copy with a new DB
3. Import your old DB and copy the files

Comment: The problem is I don't want any of the issues, documents etc, just the configuration. Is there some plugin for that, or some way to do that in the interface?

Comment: Well, the "copy issue", "copy project" may help if you want templates. Then, please explore the DB and make your changes.